# cron lacks permissions to run a script

Tags: macos, bash, permission, cron

I have a script (which backs up, using `rclone`) that I can run from the Terminal  or Automator after `chmod a+x`, with no permissions problems.

However, when this script is run in cron (or `launchd`), stderr shows  `"/bin/bash: /Users/joshua/script.sh: Operation not permitted."`

I am more familiar with Ubuntu, where this approach works fine.

What do I need to do here?

Edit: The above question remains relevant, but note that `launchd` is the favored cron replacement for Mac, while Automator is available for application-level scheduling.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the proper two programs to give full access to are:

```
cron
terminal.app
```

See [rsync in cron on Catalina no longer working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375383/rsync-in-cron-on-catalina-no-longer-working)

Comment: Thank you. But (1) I am using rclone, not rsync. Does the same apply to rclone? (2) Doesn't it seem from the error that the program failing on authorization errors is bash rather than rclone?  (3) Why the terminal.app? This is a background process.

Comment: Add cron, that should be all since your terminal is working. @JoshuaFox

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is to use Automator, not cron, [as in this example](http://macosxautomation.com/automator/calendar/index.html).

Answer (score -2):

There is two solutions that you can try. The first one I recommend however the second one might also help but it is not an ideal solution.

**First Solution:**
Assuming, you are on macOS higher than 10.12

1. Choose ‘**System Preferences**’
2. Choose “**Security & Privacy**” control panel
3. Now select the “**Privacy**” tab, then from the left-side menu select “**Full Disk Access**”
4. Click the lock icon in the lower-left corner of the preference panel and authenticate with an admin-level login
5. Now click the [+] plus button to add an application with full disk access

[image]

6. Navigate to the /Applications/Utilities/ folder and choose “Terminal” to grant Terminal with Full Disk Access privileges

[image]

7. Relaunch Terminal, the “Operation not permitted” error messages will be gone

**Second solution (I personally don't recommend this)**

1. Reboot your Mac into Recovery Mode by restarting your computer and holding down  <kbd>Command+R</kbd>  until the Apple logo appears on your screen.
2. Click **Utilities** > **Terminal**.
3. In the Terminal window, type in:

   ```
     csrutil disable
   ```
4. Restart your Mac.

Comment: Thank you, but the program that needs permissions seems to be cron, not Terminal. In fact, Terminal already had these permissions and the script would run from Terminal. I tried your instructions, and got the same error from cron. Also, I think the permission needed is to run a script, not Full Disk Access. How do I give the permissions needed here ?

Comment: You should add `cron` to “System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Full Disk Access”.

I did this by running `open /usr/bin/`, which opened a Finder window that allowed me to easily drag/drop the `cron` program into the “Full Disk Access” list.

Comment: There is no `cron` in /usr/bin. `ls /usr/bin/cron*` shows ` 
`/usr/bin/crontab`only -- so is that the one that should get permissions?

Comment: Also, even after adding `/usr/bin/crontab` for Full Disk Access, the same error appears.

Comment: `cron` might be in `/bin`, `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin`. Enabling `crontab` will not help.

Comment: Don't keep the script in a user folder.  You're being stopped because cron runs as root, not as you, and thus does not have access to the directory location of the script.

Comment: @MarcWilson If it would be a unix-level access right issue the error message would be different.

Comment: @nohillside How do you figure?  That looks like a SIP error to me,

Comment: @MarcWilson Probably (or something related to that). But your comment implies that cron does not have access because the script is in the folder of the user, and that wouldn't be a SIP issue. Anyway, if the crontab is installed by the user it's content is executed as said user so this wouldn't be a problem.