# rsync in cron on Catalina no longer working

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, catalina, cron

I have various rsync entries in `crontab` that worked reliably right up until the moment I upgraded to Catalina.

```
00 04 * * * /usr/local/bin/rsync --archive /Volumes/FOO me@remote.example:BAR
```

Here `rsync` is installed via `brew install rsync` (and it is still the correct version post-upgrade). And it doesn't much matter where `rsync` is going: from a remote server to my local disk, from one local disk to another local disk, from my local disk to a remote server. The jobs simply do not work.

Copying/pasting the exact command out of crontab and running it directly *does* work, though.

Adding `-vv` to the cron job, I see that the list of files being evaluated simply isn't complete. Whole directories are excluded. Some files are listed... some files are not listed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This requires adding `cron` to the Full Disk Access list.

Open System Preferences : Security & Privacy : Privacy : Full Disk Access

Both `rsync` and `cron` must be included on this list. Before Catalina, listing only `rsync` would work. On Catalina, `rsync` by itself only lets you run `rsync` by hand. For it to work within `cron`, `cron` must also be on the list separately.

(In the Full Disk Access preference pane, hitting Command+Shift+G will allow typing `/usr/sbin/` in order to then choose `cron`)

Comment: Good answer. Just like you have to grant terminal.app full disk access to initiate the equivalent `rsync` command, `cron` needs it or you will get permission errors on some protected directories in Catalina. Are you sure `rsync` is needed once cron is added?  I have terminal app added so maybe that’s the difference

Comment: I don't know if `rsync` needs to be listed if it's only ever going to be invoked by cron. I would expect to sometimes want to `rsync` by hand too, so I just left both.